# Qt dll deployment on windows

Tags: windows, qt, deployment

I have got a strange problem with my deployment of an Qt application. I created a Zip with all the necessary dlls and my binary on my Windows XP 32 bit box, where the application worked just fine,

Then I tested this on my laptop running windows 7 64 bit, giving me strange results. The window icons are back to the default ones and my system tray icon is invisible. Everything else is working.
As I paint a logo from the same resource file on the window (and this works on both machines) the resource file should be loading fine.

I then copied the dlls (that I installed with the same installer) from my win7 machine to the directory of my binary and the icons work again. I checked the dlls hash and they are identical.

Also I tried these dlls on my XP machine, and this time it does not show the icons.

This is quite strange because the dlls are installed from the same package and are identical, but are not working on the other machine.

Is there anything I have overlooked?

I am using QT 4.7 and the msvs2008 installer plus addin.

Comment: Did you deploy imageformats plugins with your application?

Comment: Oh, no, I guess I did not. I will try this right now. Edit: I just tried it and didn't any good. I have deployed plugins/imageformats and plugins/iconengines

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you deploy the plugins to your application directory you have to use the directories imageformats and iconengines (without the plugin/ prefix).
See the Documentation about [Deploying Plugins](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html)

Edit: And if you use QML, you also have to copy the content of the "imports" directory (also without the imports/ prefix) to your application directory.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what was wrong. Also, thanks to Kamil Kilmek :)