# Qt Encoding Questions

Tags: qt, internationalization

I am writing a Qt program in windows with international support.
The code looks like this:

```
QTextCodec *p = QTextCodec::codecForName("GBK");
```

When the program runs on GBK-local machines, it works just fine, but with a non-GBK environment, p always has the value of NULL. I am sure that the target environment has the GBK code-page installed.

Why is this happening? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for the GBK-codec is in qcncodecs4.dll, which is located in the codecs plugin directory. Your deployed program has to find this plugin: See my answer to the Question [Qt dll deployment on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047366/qt-dll-deployment-on-windows/4049823#4049823)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I followed the instructions on Qt document:
1. add a line to main.cpp: Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qcncodecs)
2. add a line to pro: QTPLUGIN += qcncodecs
But I get a build error: :: error: cannot find -lqcncodecs

Comment: Are you linking Qt statically? Because if you're not, there is no need to link it with your binary. Just make sure it is available to the deployed program, e.g.: copy it to a plugins folder alongside the app and set up the qt.conf file accordingly.

Comment: Yes I am building Qt statically and now everything works fine. Thank you everyone.