# Qt: QWebview not displaying jpg, gif, png images on another machines

Tags: qt, qt4, release, qtwebkit, qwebview

Today I came across a very strange error with `QWebView` which I cannot resolve myself.

I included a `QWebView` widget in my application. When I set a URL or a piece of HTML code to display (with `QWebView::setUrl()` or `QWebView::setHtml()`), it works very well on my machine. It also works on all machines that have Qt installed, but not on those without it. I compiled a release build and included all necessary libraries as shared (*QtWebKit4.dll*, *QtNetwork4.dll* etc.), so I guess my error lies in that I forgot to include some libraries.

If anybody has already had such an error, I would be very grateful for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to include the relevant Qt image processing plugin libraries, which are located in `qt/plugins/imageformats` (and maybe also `qt/plugins/iconengines` ). I haven't deployed any webkit apps, so I'm not certain about this.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to this question: [Qt dll deployment on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047366/qt-dll-deployment-on-windows)