# How to make QWebView load external JPG resources?

Tags: qt, networking, qt4, qwebview, qwebkit

QWebView for some weird reason doesn't want to load JPG images. How do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911232/qt-qwebview-not-displaying-jpg-gif-png-images-on-another-machines

Answer (score 1):

try this options

```
/*QWebView * view*/
view->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls,true);
view->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls,true);
view->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled,true);
view->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages,true);
```

this may help