# Program only executes if I run it in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt

I have been trying to find a solution for this problem but I haven't been able to see/find any answer that correctly solves it.

I coded a program (Qt +  OpenCV) that works fine when I run it with Visual Studio, but trying to run the executable it simply does not execute anything. The program doesn't give any error: it just never starts.

I am not sure where to start checking what is happening and why it is not even starting (I could understand lack of libraries, some other error..).

I am basically interested on what are the best way of checking why a program runs when executed from the IDE and not from the executable created. As I said, I was expecting an error message if something was wrong. Any ideas? Any good programming advice regarding how to avoid this problem in the future?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am coding with a Windows XP machine. It doesn't work in this machine when I try to execute the file. It executes normally on a W7 machine but not in other W7 machine.

Answer (score 3):

The executable will need the QT libraries on the computer that you are running it on. On linux there is command (I think ldd) that will show you what libraries your executable needs. I am not sure about Windows but there should be something similar. At least on a linux computer it will not necessarily give you an error if the QT libraries are missing. The executable just seems to do nothing.

Comment: In one of the configurations that is not working I have all the Qt libraries; I remember that I forgot one library before and it let me know (an error was displayed).

Comment: @sergi - the compiler will tell you if you missed a lib from the linker, but it doesn't know if a dll is missing at runtime. the qt vs-addin will put the Qt bin directory into the path environment for runnign inside VS

Comment: @Martin, I was talking outside of Visual Studio. Placing the executable in a folder with a missing dll gave me an error (alert window), while with this executable it does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the executable into the same directory as the .dll files in the Qt 'bin' directory.

If that works then you just need to put the Qt bin directory into your path, or copy the dlls into the windows\system directory

Comment: Thanks, I will recheck this; it is weird, though, that it complained for several dll previously but not in this case. Any reason for this to happen? Basically, until now, every time that a dll was forgotten, the executable gave an error and I am not sure why now it is not complaining; I am really curious on knowing why could this change.

Comment: @sergi, one issue i have had with Qt, a lot of Qt apps come with the mingw builds of the Qt dlls. these aren't compatible with VS. I've installed an app, it put itself on the path and my own projects which are built in VS suddenly fail with a cryptic error.  It's possible a VS app calling into a gcc built dll could just cause a silent crash

Answer (score 0):

You need not only the correct dlls in your path (best in the application directory), but also the plugins in the correct location. See my answer to the question: [Qt dll deployment on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047366/qt-dll-deployment-on-windows/4049823#4049823).