# QPixmap image loading problem

Tags: qt, png, qpixmap

Basically I am trying to load the image as a texture using QPixmap:

```
texture[T_WALL] = bindTexture(QPixmap(":/images/wall.png"), GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The code works on my development machine, but not in the vm / other pcs without QT. Initially I was using jpegs and just assumed that I messed up the plugins, but as I understand, no plugins are needed for png files so I have no idea where the problem is.

Results are the same when loading local files and using Qt resources.

I am deploying libgcc_s_dw2-1.ddl, mingwm10.dll, QtCore4.dll, QtGui4.dll, QtOpenGL4.dll. Do I need anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an imageformats directory to your application directory and put qmng4.dll there. See my answer to the question [Qt dll deployment on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047366/qt-dll-deployment-on-windows/4049823#4049823)
If it still does not work, get the [Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027) which contains dgbview.exe that allows you to watch qDebug messages (even for release builds).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on dgbview.exe. This allowed me to figure out that textures are being loaded, but are not displayed properly.