# Qt jpeg can't work on my friend's PC

Tags: image, qt, qt4, jpeg

I am finishing a Qt app, but I encounted a problem. Here is it:

I use this code to load image into a QGraphicsScene:

```
QFile file(fileName);
        if(file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)){
            QByteArray data=file.readAll ();
            pixmapItem.loadFromData (data,"jpeg");
        }
```

It works on my computer, but when I give this app to my friend, he just can't show this image. I Googled and searched Stack Overflow about this issue, which sounds like I need jpeg plugins.

So, I do this:

1. I copy qjpeg4.dll from C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\imageformats into my app root dir.---->failed.
2. I copy entire imageformats directory as a subdirectory of my app toor dir. ---->also failed.

So, how can I distribute my app to my friends? It works in my computer, so, it can do work on others', can't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to deploy the Qt DLLs and the plugin directories, see my answer to the question [Qt dll deployment on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047366/qt-dll-deployment-on-windows).

Comment: Yes, it works. But I also need one line at the beginning of the application: `Application::addLibraryPath("plugins")`, here plugins means a subdirectory which contains imageformats dir with `dlls` inside. :)