# Qt4 - On the target PC cannot read JPEG images

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, jpeg, portability

I am developing a Qt program that on the development machine works properly, but on the target machines can display all the widgets but cannot show JPEG images.

Launching the program from the command line (on the target), I get these warnings:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 3
QPainter::setFont: Painter not active
QPainter::setFont: Painter not active
QImage::pixel: coordinate (27,965) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (180,965) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (333,965) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (486,965) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (639,965) out of range
QImage::pixel: coordinate (792,965) out of range
```

From my logs I can see that the loaded image is zero bytes long.
The original JPEG images to load are OK.
On the target machine I copied all the Qt DLLs, including `qjpeg4.dll` (which is also located in the `imageformats` executable subdirectory).
The paths are all set correctly.

The code must be OK, since it works on my computer. The issues must be in the target configuration.

Windows 7 - Qt 4.8 - MinGW - GCC 4.6

Comment: Is qjpeg4.dll located in the deployment directory say ~MyExecutableDirectory\imageformats? 

If it is, maybe you compiled the code in Debug mode, so the qjpeg4d.dll (note the letter 'd' after the name) is required instead of qjpeg4.dll?

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-plugins.html

Comment: Copy the imageformats folder and contents to the same location as the executable.

Comment: 1 more: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#setLibraryPaths

Comment: This question is asked about once a month: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241141/embedded-jpg-resources-not-loading-in-qt-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500468/qt-jpeg-cant-work-on-my-friends-pc?rq=1